# Why is it preferable to write func( const Class &value )?

Tags: c++, coding-style

Why would one use `func( const Class &value )` rather than just `func( Class value )`?  Surely modern compilers will do the most efficient thing using either syntax.  Is this still necessary or just a hold over from the days of non-optimizing compilers?

- <s>Just to add, gcc will produce similar assembler code output for either syntax.  Perhaps other compilers do not?</s>

Apparently, this is just not the case.  I had the impression from some code long ago that gcc did this, but experimentation proves this wrong.  Credit is due to to Michael Burr, whose answer to a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/552134/) would be nominated if given here.

Comment: "Surely modern compilers will do the most efficient thing using either syntax." Computers don't do what you want them to do, they do what you tell them to do!

Comment: "gcc willproduce similar assembler code for either" - can you support that assertion? If it's true, the gcc has a bug.

Comment: It's possible that gcc will produce similar assembler code for either in particular circumstances, perhaps when passing an int.  It certainly shouldn't if there's a nontrivial copy constructor around.

Comment: See here for an explanation of why compilers cannot generally optimize a pass-by-value to be a pass-by-const-ref: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/552134/why-isnt-pass-struct-by-reference-a-common-optimization/552155#552155

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There are two large semantic differences between the two signatures.

The first is the use of `&` in the type name.  This signals the value is passed by reference.  Removing this causes the object to be passed by value which will essentially pass a copy of the object into the function (via the copy constructor).  For operations which simply need to read data (typical for a `const &`) doing a full copy of the object creates unnecessary overhead.  For classes which are not small or are collections, this overhead is not trivial.

The second is the use of `const`.  This prevents the function from accidentally modifying the contents of value via the `value` reference.  It allows the caller some measure of assurance the value will not be mutated by the function.  Yes, passing a copy gives the caller a much deeper assurance of this in many cases.

Comment: Even with a copy, I usually write `func(const Value myVal)` so that I don't accidentally try to modify a temporary object within the function (unless it is passed by value just for this). This is just a small trick to avoid hours of tracking why the object state has not changed after the execution of `func` :)

Answer (score 8):

The first form doesn't create a copy of the object, it just passes a reference (pointer) to the existing copy. The second form creates a copy, which can be expensive. This isn't something that is optimized away: there are semantic differences between having a copy of an object vs. having the original, and copying requires a call to the class's copy constructor.

For very small classes (like <16 bytes) with no copy constructor it is probably more efficient to use the value syntax rather than pass references. This is why you see `void foo(double bar)` and not `void foo(const double &var)`. But in the interests of not micro-optimizing code that doesn't matter, as a general rule you should pass all real-deal objects by reference and only pass built-in types like `int` and `void *` by value.

Answer (score 8):

There is a **huge** difference which nobody has mentioned yet: object slicing.  In some cases, you may *need* `const&` (or `&`) to get correct behavior.

Consider another class `Derived` which inherits from `Class`.  In client code, you create an instance of `Derived` which you pass to `func()`.  If you have `func(const Class&)`, that same instance will get passed.  As others have said, `func(Class)` will make a copy, you will have a *new* (temporary) instance of `Class` (not `Derived`) in `func`.

This difference in behavior (not performance) can be important if `func` in turn does a downcast.  Compare the results of running the following code:

```
#include <typeinfo.h>

struct Class
{
    virtual void Foo() {};
};
class Derived : public Class {};

void f(const Class& value)
{
    printf("f()\n");

    try
    {
        const Derived& d = dynamic_cast<const Derived&>(value);
        printf("dynamic_cast<>\n");
    }
    catch (std::bad_cast)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "bad_cast\n");
    }
}

void g(Class value)
{
    printf("g()\n");

    try
    {
        const Derived& d = dynamic_cast<const Derived&>(value);
        printf("dynamic_cast<>\n");
    }
    catch (std::bad_cast)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "bad_cast\n");
    }
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    Derived d;
    f(d);
    g(d);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: +1. And in particular, object slicing means that the compiler *must not* make the optimisation the questioner expects (at least for types that might be polymorphic), because then the object would not be sliced, even though the standard requires it to be.

Answer (score 4):

> Surely modern compilers will do the
>   most efficient thing using either
>   syntax

The compiler doesn't compile what you "mean", it compiles what you *tell it to*. Compilers are only smart for lower level optimizations and problems the programmer overlooks (such as computation inside a for loop, dead code etc).

What you tell the compiler to do in the second example, is to make a copy of the class - which it will do without thinking - even if you didn't use it, that's what you asked the compiler to do.

The second example explicitly asks the compiler to use the same variable - conserving space and precious cycles (no copy is needed). The const is there for mistakes - since `Class &value` can be written to (sometimes it's desired).

Answer (score 4):

Here are the differences between some parameter declarations:

```
                           copied  out  modifiable
func(Class value)           Y       N    Y
func(const Class value)     Y       N    N
func(Class &value)          N       Y    Y
func(const Class &value)    N       N    N
```

where:

- copied: a copy of the input parameter is made when the function is called
- out: value is an "out" parameter, which means modifications made within func() will be visible outside the function after it returns
- modifiable: value can be modified within func()

So the differences between `func(Class value)` and `func(const Class &value)` are:

- The first one makes a copy of the input parameter (by calling the Class copy constructor), and allows code inside func() to modify `value`
- The second one does *not* make a copy, and does *not* allow code inside func() to modify `value`

Answer (score 1):

If you use the former, and then try to change `value`, by accident, the compiler will give you an error.

If you use the latter, and then try to change `value`, it won't.

Thus the former makes it easier to catch mistakes.

Answer (score 1):

The first example is pass by reference. Rather than pass the type, C++ will pass a reference to the object (generally, references are implemented with pointers... So it's likely an object of size 4 bytes)... In the second example, the object is passed by value... if it is a big, complex object then likely it's a fairly heavyweight operation as it involves copy construction of a new "Class".

Answer (score 1):

The reason that an optimizing compiler can't handle this for you is the issue of separate compilation.  In C++, when the compiler is generating code for a caller, it may not have access to the code of the function itself.  The most common calling convention that I know of usually has the caller invoke the copy-constructor which means it's not possible for the compilation of the function itself to prevent the copy constructor if it's not necessary.

Comment: Actually, gcc does do this optimization, even with -O0.

Comment: Hmm, I just tested it (using gcc 4.2.1 under Snow Leopard) by putting a printf() into the copy constructor of a class, and then passing an object of that class to a function.  Sure enough, the copy constructor was called.  

In fact, I'm pretty sure the C++ standard requires the copy constructor to be called in that scenario -- to optimize the call out would be a compiler bug.

Comment: @casualcoder - could you post the code you say GCC performs this optimization on?  Does it do the same if the caller and callee are not in the same source file?

Answer (score 0):

The only time that passing a parameter by value is preferable is when you are going to copy the parameter anyway.

```
std::string toUpper( const std::string &value ) {
    std::string retVal(value);
    transform(retVal.begin(), retVal.end(), charToUpper());
    return retVal;
}
```

Or

```
std::string toUpper( std::string value ) {
    transform(value.begin(), value.end(), charToUpper());
    return value;
}
```

In this case the second example is the same speed as the first if the value parameter is a regular object, but faster if the value parameter is a R-Value.

Although most compilers will do this optimisation already I don't expect to rely on this feature till C++0X, esp since I expect it could confuse most programmers who would probably change it back.

See [Want Speed? Pass by Value.](http://cpp-next.com/archive/2009/08/want-speed-pass-by-value/) for a better explaination than I could give.

Comment: Should be `return value;` in the second function.