# How is this x86 assembly code receiving and storing the data returned from subroutine?

Tags: c++, assembly, x86

I have a c++ code that calls the address of an exported function from another dll and receive a struct back. The c++ code looks like below (I changed the variable names to A, B, C...):

```
// .h 
struct _A { unsigned char _B[32]; } A;

// .cpp
typedef struct _A* (__cdecl *_C)();
_C C = NULL;
...
C = (_C)GetProcAddress(..., ...);
A = *C();
```

The above code (just the `A = *C();` part), when compiled in VS 2015, turns into the following code listing:

```
A DB 020H DUP (?)
...
call DWORD PTR C
mov  esi, eax
mov  esx, 8
mov  edi, OFFSET A
```

How (and where) is the pointer passed from the subroutine stored by just three lines of mov? I can't figure out how the data passed from the subroutine is being stored for later references.

Just out of curiosity, I tried changing struct _A to have _B[11] instead of _B[32], and the code changed to the following:

```
call DWORD PTR C
mov  ecx, DWORD PTR [eax]
mov  DWORD PTR A, ecx
mov  edx, DWORD PTR [eax+4]
mov  DWORD PTR A+4, edx
...
```

So this makes sense to me. It's reading from eax and copying to A like expected. But how is the first assembly code retrieving and storing the struct returned from the subroutine?

Comment: Return value is passed in ax.

Comment: @JesperJuhl I know that it's passed on eax, but how is that being stored for later references? For instance, later in the code when that A is actually referred to, all it seems to be doing is push OFFSET A and then it can magically refer to the struct that I got back from C(), but how (and when) was this copied? I can't figure that part out since all I see is three movs that are filling esi, esx and edi and doing nothing else...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But how is the first assembly code retrieving and storing the struct returned from the subroutine?

First of all, it doesn't return a struct, it returns a *pointer to* a struct in EAX.  The function's return type is `struct _A*`.  You don't show *what* it's pointing to; perhaps some static buffer in a non-thread-safe function?

**It looks like you left out a [`rep movsd`](http://felixcloutier.com/x86/REP:REPE:REPZ:REPNE:REPNZ.html) in the first example after setting up esi, edi, and ecx (your `esx` is obviously a typo)**.  This will memcpy `4*8` = 32 bytes from the pointer returned in EAX to the static storage for `A`.  (Note the `mov edi, offset A` to get the actual address of `A` into EDI.)

With a smaller struct, it copies it with a few `mov` instructions instead of setting up for a `rep movsd` (which has considerable startup overhead and is a bad choice for a 32-byte copy if SSE was available).  i.e. it fully unrolls a copy loop.

---

(In the first version of the, I didn't look closely enough at the code, and based on the wording thought you were actually returning a struct by value when you talked about returning a struct.  Seems a shame to delete what I wrote about that related case.  Instead of *hidden* pointer, you have an explicit pointer to an object that exists in the C++, not just in the asm implementation of what the C++ abstract machine does.)

**Large struct by-value returns are returned by hidden pointer** (the caller passes in a pointer as the first arg, and the function returns it in EAX for the convenience of the caller).  This is typical for most calling conventions; see links to calling convention docs in the [x86 tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info).

The *value* of `A` itself is 32 bytes, and doesn't fit in a register.  Often in asm you need a pointer to an object.  `push OFFSET A` is probably part of calling a function that takes A by reference (probably explicitly in the C++ source; I don't think any of the standard x86 calling conventions implement pass-by-value as pass-by-const-reference, [only by non-const reference e.g. for Windows x64, and maybe others](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/552134/why-isnt-pass-struct-by-reference-a-common-optimization/51429133#51429133)).

---

Your compiler probably couldn't optimize `A = foo();` (returning a large struct by value) by passing the address of `A` directly as the output pointer.

`A` is global, and the callee is allowed to assume that its return-value buffer doesn't alias the global `A`.  The caller can't assume that the function doesn't access `A` directly, but according to the C++ abstract machine the value of `A` doesn't change until after the function returns.

Comment: Thank you! I totally missed that `rep movsd` but yes, I found that 2 lines below. I think it makes sense now. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: Peter, his function returns a pointer, not a struct, so it can’t use the hidden parameter that is used for struct return.

Comment: @prl: oh lol, yeah it's not hidden, it's the C++ source dereferencing the pointer to do the copying in the caller.  /facepalm.