# Pointer to struct or struct itself?

Tags: c, performance, pointers, struct

Consider this code:

```
struct s { /* ... */ };

void f(struct s x) { /* ... */) /* (1) */
/* or */
void f(const struct s *x) { /* ... */ } /* (2) */
```

When `struct s` has a decent size, in which case should we prefer the first form?

Comment: I personally just try to pass a pointer to the struct when it becomes large, because it's a lot faster to just pass a pointer rather than an entire large structure.

Comment: You didn't say what "decent" is. It could mean anything. Nice round numbers like 1024 bytes, are those decent? In addition, asking for preferences rather than absolutes is frowned upon on this site.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are you asking which is better?

It depends what you are trying to do - the second form with a pointer will be more efficient. But if you just want to pass a value to `f` and not have to worry about side-effects then you might go with the first signature - as long as the `struct` is not too large.

Comment: How is the second form more efficient?

Comment: @Mike: Because you are copying a pointer.  If that struct gets larger in size than a pointer (almost certainly will be the case) then you are doing more work.

Comment: I'm also not sure what side-effects you are speaking of.  Sure, the const can be cast away, but you're implementing the function, right? So, umm... don't do that or take away the const. I would prefer the second form.

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/161788/are-there-any-downsides-to-passing-structs-by-value-in-c-rather-than-passing-a).

When `struct s`is of decent size as you say, then you should avoid passing it by value, especially in recursive functions.

Passing a struct by value means that it gets copied before the function invocation. That results in slower execution and greater memory utilization. Also note that the `struct` is going to be allocating in the stack and in some systems the stack size is pretty limited.

I would suggest using a pointer in every case unless you need multiple copies of a structure to be modified by functions and you don't want those modifications only visible within each function's scope.

Comment: Wouldn't it make sense to just use a union in this case?

Comment: @NerdOfCode I don't see how a union would help in that case. Unions are essentially structs that may have multiple different interpretations and take up the space of the bigger possible interpretation.

Comment: Because each element could only one element could exist at the same time. Thus, improving the memory utilization

Comment: I am not sure I follow. We don't know anything about the struct itself. But even if we assume that a union would be more appropriate the same reasoning holds for whether passing it by value or by reference.

Answer (score -2):

Prefer the first form when you want `f` to get a copy of `x` instead of a `const` pointer to `x`.

Comment: And why is that exactly?  Care to provide some reasoning behind that statement?  I think the OP understands that a copy is going on here, that's not the question. The object is `const`, so it can't be modified (unless you are really hell bent on doing so) and you avoid a copy of the entire struct.