# Calling a C function in Python and returning 2 values

Tags: python, c, python-2.7, ctypes

I am trying to figure out how to return 2 vales from a C function that I called in python. I have read through the material online and am using struct to output the two variables. I am able to output the variables when I call this function in the same C file. However, when I try to call it in python, it still only returns one value.

This is my C code:

```
struct re_val {

    double predict_label;
    double prob_estimates;  

};

struct re_val c_func(const char* dir, double a, double b, double c, double d )
{
    double x[] = {a,b,c,d};

    printf ("x[0].index: %d \n", 1);
    printf ("x[0].value: %f \n", x[0]);

    printf ("x[1].index: %d \n", 2);
    printf ("x[1].value: %f \n", x[1]);

    printf ("x[2].index: %d \n", 3);
    printf ("x[2].value: %f \n", x[2]);

    printf ("x[3].index: %d \n", 4);
    printf ("x[3].value: %f \n", x[3]);

    printf ("\nThis is the Directory: %s \n", dir); 

    struct re_val r;
    r.predict_label = 5.0;
    r.prob_estimates = 8.0;   

    return r;

}
```

This is my Python code:

```
calling_function = ctypes.CDLL("/home/ruven/Documents/Sonar/C interface/Interface.so")
calling_function.c_func.argtypes = [ctypes.c_char_p, ctypes.c_double, ctypes.c_double, ctypes.c_double, ctypes.c_double]
calling_function.c_func.restype =  ctypes.c_double
q = calling_function.c_func("hello",1.3256, 2.45, 3.1248, 4.215440)
print q
```

Currently, when I run my python file in the terminal it outputs this:

```
x[0].index: 1 
x[0].value: 1.325600 

x[1].index: 2 
x[1].value: 2.450000 

x[2].index: 3 
x[2].value: 3.124800 

x[3].index: 4 
x[3].value: 4.215440 

This is the Directory: hello 

5.0
```

Instead,I would like it to output this:

```
x[0].index: 1 
x[0].value: 1.325600 

x[1].index: 2 
x[1].value: 2.450000 

x[2].index: 3 
x[2].value: 3.124800 

x[3].index: 4 
x[3].value: 4.215440 

This is the Directory: hello 

5.0
8.0
```

Comment: I don't know this code will work or not but. check this link. it may be helpful to you.  https://gist.github.com/Overdrivr/cdd58cea15d7e28c50ea

Comment: The problem is in`calling_function.c_func.restype =  ctypes.c_double` You are essentially telling to ctypes the the function result type is a c_double, whereas the function from you c library doesn't return a double, it returns a `struct re_val`.

Comment: @hetepeperfan I thought about that but i couldn't find a way to change calling_function.c_func.restype to return a struct as ctypes.c_struct
 does not exist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your C code is fine, the problem you are experiencing is in how you use python ctypes. You should tell that the function returns a `struct re_val` and not a double:

```
calling_function.c_func.restype =  ctypes.c_double
```

The above makes the function return a single double value in the eyes of ctypes. You should tell python that the function returns a structure:

```
import ctypes as ct

# Python representation of the C struct re_val
class ReVal(ct.Structure):
    _fields_ = [("predict_label", ct.c_double),("prob_estimates", ct.c_double)]

calling_function = ctypes.CDLL("/home/ruven/Documents/Sonar/C interface/Interface.so")
calling_function.c_func.argtypes = [ctypes.c_char_p, ctypes.c_double, ctypes.c_double, ctypes.c_double, ctypes.c_double]
# and instead of c_double use:
calling_function.c_func.restype = ReVal
```

This way you tell python's ctypes that the function returns a aggregate object that is a subclass of ctypes.Structure that matches the `struct re_val` from the c library.

**NOTE** Be very carefull with argtypes and restype, if you use these incorrectly it is easy to crash the python interpreter. Then you get a segfault instead of a nice traceback.

Comment: Hi, unfortunately when I run the program it gives me the following message:
<__main__.ReVal object at 0x7fb3bd1e0560>

Comment: Yes, that is right, but that is the struct as returned by ctypes, it is still an aggregate. So the returned object has two fields "predict_label" and "prob_estimates". So you can access them via `q.predict_label` and `q.prob_estimates`
You generally need to take some extra steps to extract the values from the struct.